# Implementing HttpSession in Java Se

Tags: java, http, session, java-server

I am using com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer as my HTTP Server with JAVA SE. Specification can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/package-summary.html

I need to keep some basic data into my session and since there is no HttpSession object here, I need to create my own. But I need to keep it as simple as possible (as always).

Any tips would be appreciated, even short ones.
My source code is available at: https://github.com/fidelio-coder/HttpServer

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why can't you just use embedded Tomcat or Jetty and use full Servlet spec? It works in Java SE as well.

Comment: for educational purposes, we cannot use any third-party. maybe to show our understanding of core of java?!

Comment: OK. In that case you have to learn how servlets deal with sessions, search for JSESSIONID cookie and URL rewriting. And BTW `HttpServer` is **not** a standard Java.

Answer (score 3):

If you did something with JSF, you saw that variables can be in different scopes: application, session, request, and custom (your own kind of map). So for a clean design the session variables belong to a more general class, than merely the HttpSession.

As already said, using sun classes might lead to some pitfalls, especially when switching from local development under Windows to deployment under Linux (which often uses the **OpenJDK**).

There cannot be said much more about HttpSession, besides the API.

Though you want to do all thing yourself, I had to think of [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/), that provides security, sessions and such. Sessions between local Java SE applications and Java EE server! It might be worth looking into their ideas/APIs.

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip. Unfortunately, that is the case! I am encountering an unusual situation I guess.